# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined inside Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a problem with "Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined". Below are the source codes. Appreciate your help.

```
$http.get("js/project/data.json").then(function(response) {
        //$scope.case = response.data.caseno;    
        $scope.case = response.data.caseno.map(function(elem) { 
            return elem.toLowerCase(); 
        }); 
    });

    console.log($scope.project.ProjectCaseNo.toLowerCase());

    if($scope.case.indexOf($scope.project.ProjectCaseNo.toLowerCase()) != -1 ){
        $scope.glyphicon = 'glyphicon-ok green';
        $scope.CaseMessage = 'Valid Case No.';
    }else{
        $scope.glyphicon = 'glyphicon-remove red';
        $scope.CaseMessage = 'Invalid Case No.';
    };
};
```

Comment: Debug your code, find where the problem is, add the information to your question. Then we can try to help you. But the error is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Tip : JS is asynchronous. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function

Answer (score 2):

change it something like this:

```
    $scope.VerifyCaseNo = function(){
        $http.get("js/project/data.json").then(function(response) {
            //$scope.case = response.data.caseno;    
            $scope.case = response.data.caseno.map(function(elem) { 
                return elem.toLowerCase(); 
            }); 
            console.log($scope.project.ProjectCaseNo.toLowerCase());

            if($scope.case.indexOf($scope.project.ProjectCaseNo.toLowerCase()) != -1 ){
                $scope.glyphicon = 'glyphicon-ok green';
                $scope.CaseMessage = 'Valid Case No.';
            }else{
                $scope.glyphicon = 'glyphicon-remove red';
                $scope.CaseMessage = 'Invalid Case No.';
            };
        });
    };
```

Your `$scope.case` will be undefined before the `$http.get()` operation is complete. so you get the Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined error!

Comment: Thanks guys for the solution. It's working as expected. Need to understand more on the $http concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String(yourValue).indexOf('')`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14592312)

Comment: @beryllium seems like an attempt to answer to me